# Which assembly do I need to include for the C# where extension method?

Tags: c#, lambda

What is the name of the assembly that must be included for the `Where` extension method? I can't find it's name on google, and apparently it's not one of these:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to...

1. add a **reference to the `System.Core` assembly** to your project; and
2. add a **`using System.Linq` directive** at the start of your source file(s).

Please note that a `using` directive does not import an *assembly* into your project, it only imports symbols from a specified *namespace*. In order for a namespace to become available, you must first reference an assembly that defines types in that namespace.

If you're using Microsoft Visual Studio and you want to add an assembly reference to your project, open the *Project Explorer* panel, right-click on your project and go either to *Properties* or *Add reference...*.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Linq
```

Should do it.